# Ack! Where do I find the spell descriptions for casters?

Tags: dnd-next-playtest

I've downloaded the play test and the clerics' and wizard's spells are not on their character sheets. It is unclear from the character sheet where those are listed.

Where can I find their spell descriptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are now two places to find spells for casters.

The spells needed for BD&D characters (a subset of the Cleric and Wizard spells) are listed in the [BD&D Players document](http://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/dnd/PlayerDnDBasicRules_v0.2_PrintFriendly.pdf), starting at page 82. Also some spells required for Horde of The Dragon Queen are found in the [supplemental material](http://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/dnd/HoardDragonQueen_Supplement1_PF.pdf) for that adventure on p. 24.

All of these spells can also be found in the Players Handbook starting on p. 207.

Answer (score 7):

In the latest packets, there is a separate document for the spells, in alphabetical order.